# Enabling window switcher in Ubuntu Budgie 17.04

Tags: desktop-environments, window-manager, application-switcher, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

I have Ubuntu budgie 17.04 (budgie-desktop 10.2.9). While pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between the windows, the windows are switched randomly and I am not able to select which window to shift.

This feature was available in Ubuntu 16.04 but not in Ubuntu-budgie-17.04.

[image]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the hopeful solution to the problem. Thanks to @Dustin Krysak and @David Mohammed of Ubuntu-budgie community...!

- Go into the budgie-welcome application, ensure that the backports PPA is enabled. Then update. This feature was re added in Budgie 10.3.

***or***

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntubudgie/backports

- Then

> sudo apt update

&&

> sudo apt install budgie-desktop budgie-indicator-applet

Log-out and Log-in.

If the above steps donot work.....then...

> sudo apt update

&&

> sudo apt dist-upgrade

It will upgrade the system to latest version of budgie-desktop. The switcher feature was added in version > 10.3.*

Answer (score 4):

Not *literally* an answer to your *textual* question, but an answer to what you refer to in the image:

#### Window Previews

In the meantime, Ubuntu Budgie got his own Window Previews (17.04 >):

[image]

Usage is simple: after adding the applet to the panel, simply

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get an overview of all windows (on current workspace), or
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get an overview of all windows of the currently active window's application.

Simply <kbd>Tab</kbd> will subsequently browse through the overview.

#### Installation

...is best done from Budgie Welcome > <kbd>Install Software</kbd> > <kbd>Budgie Applets</kbd>

[image]

Comment: now known as budgie extras. you will also need to go to "Previews" app, and turn on "run".

Comment: I just removed it and I can't switch apps :D What to do?

Comment: OK oook, I went to Ubuntu Keyboard Preferences and reset Keyboard Shortcuts responsible for switching app windows.